# Replace site title <h1> with logo when logo is uploaded in customizer using <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>

Tags: theme-development, customization

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for writing a conditional statement in my header.php file using the `<?php the_custom_logo(); ?>` function, whereby if the custom logo is uploaded using the Wordpress customizer, the `<h1>` element that usually contains the site title is replaced by the custom logo, so that it doesn't display both the site title and the logo at the same time?

I am building a custom theme using the Underscores starter theme on Wordpress version 4.7.4

Here is the current code in my header.php file, with the logo currently called independently above the `.site-title` using the `<?php the_custom_logo(); ?>` function.

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="site-branding">

            <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>

            <?php
            if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
            <?php
            endif;

            $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
            if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
            <?php
            endif; ?>

        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'odtcreative' ); ?></button>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </div>
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

```
<div class="site-branding">             
    <?php
    $logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
    $logo_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $logo_id, 'full' );                  

    if ( ! empty( $logo_image ) ) : ?>
        <span class="site-logo"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $logo_image[0] ); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"/></a></span>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
    <?php
    endif;      
</div><!-- .site-branding -->
```